# I need to close a notification when the application is closed

Tags: java, android, multithreading, notifications, runnable

I have this Runnable method which send a notification once it is called and every minute sends a JSON Post on an HTTP Server. So i coded the method "sendNotification" to keep informed the user regards the "service" is running but when I close the app, the method to send the JSON stops and the notification stays active on the notification bar. I would like to close the notification as well.

```
//Runnable methods for frequency position
private final Runnable oneMinuteRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendNotification();
        getTimestamp();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getLocation();
                doPostRequest();
            }
        }).start();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000);
    }

};
```

This is the notification method

```
//Make notification when the frequency service is running
public void sendNotification() {
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, com.example.httptracker.Services.Notification.NOTIFICATION_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_run_circle_24)
            .setContentTitle("AMP Tracker")
            .setContentText("Tracker is running")
            .build();

    compat.notify(1, notification);
}
```

I looked up online and I saw only solutions with a Service class but I would need to develop a "stop service" button to cancel the notification. But it is not what I need. The notification should disappear once the app is closed or the method killed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to cancel your notification with:

```
compat.cancel(1); // assuming compat is NotificationManager instance, 1 is your id
```

in e.g. `onDestroy` of `Activity` or any place when your app is stopping `oneMinuteRunnable` looped execution

Comment: I have already tried to develop that piece of code on "onDestroy" method but it doesn`t do anything even if i try with a "Toast".